# How to plot hyperbolic grid in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hyperbolic-function

I am trying to create a hyperbolic mesh grid in Matlab, similar to

[image]

What somehow works is to project a hyperboloid onto a plane (x-z in this case):

```
t = -5:.1:5;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(t, t, t);
V = X.^2 + Y.^2 - Z.^2;
contour(squeeze(V(:, 1, :)))
```

which produces this:

[image]

which is pretty ugly and still far from what I want. I also don't like that I have to go to 3D to get something in 2D. Any idea how to produce such nice hyperbolic mesh grid in some nice way? Thanks.